# How does terraform link the state resource to the terraform code?

Tags: terraform

If I have a resource defined in terraform, how does terraform link it to the state? I have no id in my definition of the resource. Does the state file save, how I named the resource in my code?

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform each resource instance has a unique address that's generated from the tree of modules the resource is nested in, the type and name of the resource itself, and any instance key created by `count` or `for_each` argument.

Some examples of these resource instance addresses might be:

- `aws_instance.example`: a single-instance resource in the root module
- `aws_instance.example[0]`: the first instance of a resource with the `count` argument set
- `aws_instance.example["foo"]`: an instance of a resource with the `for_each` argument set, where the given map includes the key "foo".
- `module.example.aws_instance.example`: a resource inside a module called "example".
- `module.example[0].module.example2["foo"].aws_instance.example[3]`: a complex example of a resource nested two modules deep where the first module uses `count`, the second module uses `for_each`, and the resource itself uses `count`.

You can see these addresses as part of Terraform's description of the proposed changes when it creates a plan, and you can also see the addresses of the objects that Terraform's already managing by running `terraform show`.

If you run `terraform show` (after Terraform has created some objects) you'll also see that Terraform remembers whatever was the current state of each resource instance in its own state snapshots. Terraform will send this data to the provider next time you ask it to create a plan, and then the provider can use whatever subset of that data it needs to in order to recognize which remote object the resource instance is bound to.

Terraform itself (the core engine, excluding any specific providers) only tracks the full set of data most recently returned by the provider for each resource instance. It's up to the provider to decide what information from that object is part of the identifier for the remote object, although a common convention is to use an attribute named `id` to track that remote ID.